# Adding a large number from a user in python

Tags: python, string, numbers, int

```
def main():
number = input("enter large number:")
number = int(number)
result = 0

for i in number:

    result = result + i
print("result is:",result)
```

is giving me an error with the int,I'm not sure how to fix it.

I need the user to type in a large number like 2541 and it needs to be separated like 2,5,4,1 and added to give me the result of 12 is not supposed to be just 4 number but needs to be a large number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't iterate over a number, so `for i in number` will fail.

What you want is to start with the input as a string, iterate over that, then convert to an int when adding it to result:

```
number = str(input("enter large number:"))
result = 0

for i in number:
    result = result + int(i)
print("result is:",result)
```